# Process.Responding работает не коректно

Tags: c#, процесс

написал вот такой код для вывода списка процессов и вывода их статуса (то есть: работает он или приостановлен)
вот сам код:

```
foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    string res = proc.Responding.ToString();
    if (res == "True")
    {
        res = "working";
    }
    else if (res == "False")
    {
        res = "suspended";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(proc.Id.ToString() + ":::" + proc.ProcessName + ":::" + res);
}
```

для теста приостановил VsCode:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но моя программа считает что приостановлен лишь 1 процесс VsCode'a:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так и какие решения есть для того чтобы узнать замороженные процессы?

Comment: А зачем `Responding.ToString()`, вы не умеете с булевыми величинами работать? Так то на работу не влияет, но выглядит диковато )

Comment: Для того, чтоб понять почему не так, достаточно зайти [в документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.responding), где будет черный по белому написано `Получает значение, указывающее, отвечает или нет пользовательский интерфейс.`. Это не состояние процесса, которое вы видите в диспетчере, это показатель зависшего интерфейса (видели наверно, когда работаете с приложением, вдруг оно зависает и при клике окно белеет, вот это оно). Если нужен именно статус процесса, то тут надо копать в дебри WinAPI, через Process и даже WMI его не получить.

Comment: @CrazyElf просто без ToString() 
я  получаю еррор связанный с наследованием

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(proc.Id + ":::" + proc.ProcessName + ":::" + proc.Responding ? "working" : "suspended")`

Comment: `if (proc.Responding)` `if (proc.Responding == true)` или `if (!proc.Responding)` `if (proc.Responding == false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, два пути, заодно узнаете что такое WinAPI.

1. Простой:

- Для этого мы берем процессы, стандартным `Process.GetProcesses();`
- Далее у каждого процесса смотрим его потоки (`.Threads`).
- Если `ThreadState` будет `Wait`, а `WaitReason` будет `Suspended`, то значит можем считать этот процесс замороженным.

В итоге получаем, например такое:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var process in processes.Where(x=>x.Threads.Cast<ProcessThread>().All(p => 
{
    if (p.ThreadState == ThreadState.Wait)
    {
        return p.WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.Suspended;
    }
    return false;
})))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{process.Id}] {process.ProcessName} : {process.Threads.Cast<ProcessThread>().All(x => x.WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.Suspended)}");
}
```

Тут уже сами делайте коллекции или что вам надо. В текущем виде на экран будет выведены все замороженные процессы.

2. Более сложный, зато интересный - WinAPI:

#### Что такое WinAPI

WinAPI - это, по сути, набор библиотек Windows, который лежит у каждого на компьютере, через которые сама OS и обрабатывает все нужное. В этих библиотеках лежат простые методы, которые на вход принимают что-то, и отдают нам что-то на выход. Работа с этим всем происходит при помощи [вызовов неуправляемого кода (P/Invoke)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke). И тут благо, что большинство методов, сама Microsoft расписала на своем сайте, что не заставит труда в поиске нужного (хоть местами это весьма ужасная документация).

#### Что нам понадобиться

1. [NtQuerySystemInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation) - это основной метод, который может предоставить нам кучу полезной информации, включая нужную нам информацию процессов. Находится он в `Ntdll.dll`.
2. Перечисление [NTSTATUS](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/shared/ntstatus.h) - так мы поймем, выполнилась нужная нам функция, или выдала ошибку, или еще что. По сути, от туда нам нужно 2 статуса `STATUS_SUCCESS` и `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH`, но вы смотрите, может что-то еще может быть полезно для конкретно вашей задачи, например, `STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW`.
3. Перечисление [SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/inc/api/ntexapi/system_information_class.htm) - это входной параметр, благодаря которому метод понимает, какую именно информацию стоит выдать. В нашем случае, нам нужен лишь `SystemProcessInformation` (0x05).
4. Структура [SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation#system_process_information) - это данные, которые вернет метод, внутри которых будет информация о процессе (его id, название, потоки, и прочее).
5. Структура [SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation#system_thread_information)  - это уже информация о потоках конкретного процесса, самая важная для нас структура, ибо именно она и содержит статус.
6. Перечисление [WaitReason](https://github.com/avplayer/avdbg/blob/master/Other/exeToc/debug/INC/NTDDK/wdm.h#L710), которое скажет причину простоя процесса.
7. Перечисление [ThreadState](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.threadstate) - состояние потока.

Как видите, наша задача сводится к тому, чтобы выполнить метод `NtQuerySystemInformation` с правильными параметрами, и прочитать из него нужные нам структуры данных. На выходе мы должны получить список процессов с их потоками и статусами.

#### Подготовление

Для начала все структуры и перечисления. Просто переписываем информацию по ссылкам в объекты C#:

```
internal enum NT_STATUS
{
    STATUS_SUCCESS = 0x00000000,
    STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = unchecked((int)0xC0000004L)
}

internal enum SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS
{
    SystemBasicInformation = 0,
    SystemPerformanceInformation = 2,
    SystemTimeOfDayInformation = 3,
    SystemProcessInformation = 5,
    SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation = 8,
    SystemHandleInformation = 16,
    SystemInterruptInformation = 23,
    SystemExceptionInformation = 33,
    SystemRegistryQuotaInformation = 37,
    SystemLookasideInformation = 45
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal class SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    internal uint NextEntryOffset;
    internal uint NumberOfThreads;
    private long _SpareLi1;
    private long _SpareLi2;
    private long _SpareLi3;
    private long _CreateTime;
    private long _UserTime;
    private long _KernelTime;

    internal ushort NameLength;
    internal ushort MaximumNameLength;
    internal IntPtr NamePtr;

    internal int BasePriority;
    internal IntPtr UniqueProcessId;
    internal IntPtr InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
    internal uint HandleCount;
    internal uint SessionId;
    internal UIntPtr PageDirectoryBase;
    internal UIntPtr PeakVirtualSize;
    internal UIntPtr VirtualSize;
    internal uint PageFaultCount;

    internal UIntPtr PeakWorkingSetSize;
    internal UIntPtr WorkingSetSize;
    internal UIntPtr QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
    internal UIntPtr QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
    internal UIntPtr QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
    internal UIntPtr QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
    internal UIntPtr PagefileUsage;
    internal UIntPtr PeakPagefileUsage;
    internal UIntPtr PrivatePageCount;

    private long _ReadOperationCount;
    private long _WriteOperationCount;
    private long _OtherOperationCount;
    private long _ReadTransferCount;
    private long _WriteTransferCount;
    private long _OtherTransferCount;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal class SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION
{
    private long _KernelTime;
    private long _UserTime;
    private long _CreateTime;

    private uint _WaitTime;
    internal IntPtr StartAddress;
    internal IntPtr UniqueProcess;
    internal IntPtr UniqueThread;
    internal int Priority;
    internal int BasePriority;
    internal uint ContextSwitches;
    internal uint ThreadState;
    internal uint WaitReason;
}
```

Как видите `WaitReason` это простое число, некий код, не очень информативный для нас, так давайте сделаем метод, который это число превратит в нужное нам значение. В C# есть для этого готовый `enum`, зовется [ThreadWaitReason](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.threadwaitreason), наша задача получить его из числа, но увы, получаемое число не совсем соответсвует тому, что нам надо, поэтому при помощи простого `switch`, нам придется делать все руками:

```
internal static ThreadWaitReason GetThreadWaitReason(int value) 
    => value switch
{
    0 or 7 => ThreadWaitReason.Executive,
    1 or 8 => ThreadWaitReason.FreePage,
    2 or 9 => ThreadWaitReason.PageIn,
    3 or 10 => ThreadWaitReason.SystemAllocation,
    4 or 11 => ThreadWaitReason.ExecutionDelay,
    5 or 12 => ThreadWaitReason.Suspended,
    6 or 13 => ThreadWaitReason.UserRequest,
    14 => ThreadWaitReason.EventPairHigh,
    15 => ThreadWaitReason.EventPairLow,
    16 => ThreadWaitReason.LpcReceive,
    17 => ThreadWaitReason.LpcReply,
    18 => ThreadWaitReason.VirtualMemory,
    19 => ThreadWaitReason.PageOut,
    _ => ThreadWaitReason.Unknown,
};
```

Можете спросить, а почему 0 и 7 это `Executive`, а 5 и 12 - это `Suspended` (и т.д.)? А вы откройте структуру, увидите там есть повторяющиеся статусы, такие как `WrExecutive`, вот индексы подобных повторений мы и соединяем в один статус, где 0 - это `Executive`, а 7 - это `WrExecutive`.

И так, с подготовлением данных мы завершили, остался сам метод, который будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
internal static extern NT_STATUS NtQuerySystemInformation(
       [In] SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass,
       [In] IntPtr SystemInformation,
       [In] int SystemInformationLength,
       [Out] out int ReturnLength);
```

Собственно, это все, что нам нужно, осталось выполнить и получить данные.

#### Пытаемся все это вызвать

Метод работает по принципу записи байт в буфер определенного размера, если этот буфер будет для нас мал, то в ответ мы получим статус `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH`, а в `out ReturnLength` будет требуемый для выполнения размер буфера. Собственно, на данный момент, наша задача, это вызвать метод, чтобы тот записал в буфер данные, а в случае его нехватки, буфер должен сам увеличится. Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
int bufferSize = 128 * 1024;
int requiredSize = 0;
NT_STATUS status;

GCHandle bufferHandle = new GCHandle();

try
{
    do
    {
        long[] buffer = new long[bufferSize];
        bufferHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS.SystemProcessInformation, bufferHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), bufferSize, out requiredSize);

        if (status == NT_STATUS.STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
        {
            if (bufferHandle.IsAllocated) bufferHandle.Free();
            bufferSize = requiredSize + 1024 * 10; // добавляем пару кб на случай появления доп. процессов во время очередного выполнения метода.
        }

    } while (status == NT_STATUS.STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);
}
finally
{
    if (bufferHandle.IsAllocated) bufferHandle.Free();
}
```

- `int bufferSize = 128 * 1024;` - мы определяем размер буфера таким, чтоб в него поместилась вся информация, о всех процессах.
- `int requiredSize = 0;` - в эту переменную метод будет возвращать размер требуемого ему буфера, чтобы уместить все данные.
- `NT_STATUS status;` - статус последнего выполнения метода, по которому мы будем крутить ниже цикл.
- `GCHandle bufferHandle = new GCHandle();` - некий объект, который будет помогать нам контролировать память.
- `try/finally` - служит для того, чтобы в самом конце выполнения всех действий, задействованная нами память почистилась.
- `do/while` - это цикл, который будет пытаться вызвать метод до тех пор, пока ему не хватит размера буфера для получения всех данных.
- Внутренности цикла думаю и так понятны, мы просто создаем новый буфер, вызываем метод, если метод кричит, что ему не хватает памяти, мы меняем размер буфера (добавив чуть про запас), и очищаем старый буфер, и крутим все по новой.

Так, с этим разобрались, теперь приступим к написанию кода, который в случае успешного статуса, получит нужную нам структуру данных:

```
if (status == NT_STATUS.STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    long totalOffset = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        IntPtr currentPtr = checked((IntPtr)(bufferHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject() + totalOffset));
        var processInformation = new SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(currentPtr, processInformation);

        //TODO

        if (processInformation.NextEntryOffset is 0) break;
        totalOffset += processInformation.NextEntryOffset;
    }
}
```

- так, как метод отдает нам весь список процессов, мы используем цикл `while` до тех пор, пока метод не отдаст значением `NextEntryOffset` 0. А до тех пор, мы крутим цикл, забирая нужные нам данные, каждый раз смещаясь по памяти на определенное кол-во байт (которые указаны в `NextEntryOffset`), попутно записывая в заранее подготовленную структуру все данные. На данном моменте мы уже начинаем получать данные, например `processInformation.UniqueProcessId` вернет нам id процесса. Нас, по сути, интересует тут лишь id и название, давайте их получим:

  ```
    var processId = processInformation.UniqueProcessId.ToInt32();

    string processName;
    if (processInformation.NamePtr == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        processName = processId switch
        {
            0 => "Idle",
            4 => "System",
            _ => processId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        };
    }
    else
    {
        processName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(processInformation.NamePtr, processInformation.NameLength / sizeof(char));
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"[{processId}] {processName}");
  ```

С именем тут как видите, не все так просто, ибо его может и не быть, может быть лишь известный id процесса (системный, например), а если имя и есть, то мы получаем не строку, а Pointer - то есть, некую точку в байтах, с которой начинается информация имени. Вот имея эту точку и размер, мы при помощи `Marshal.PtrToStringUni()` получаем нужное нам.

В итоге, в консоль у нас должны вывестись все процессы с их Id. Почти все сделано, осталось немного, а именно потоки с их статусами. Тут все тоже самое, мы должны сместиться на определенное число байт и выдернуть нужный нам участок данных, занеся его в заранее подготовленную структуру:

```
currentPtr = checked((IntPtr)((long)currentPtr + Marshal.SizeOf(processInformation)));
                   
for (int i = 0; i < processInformation.NumberOfThreads; i++)
{
    SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION threadInformation = new SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION();
    Marshal.PtrToStructure(currentPtr, threadInformation);

    var threadProcessId = threadInformation.UniqueProcess.ToInt32();
    var threadId = threadInformation.UniqueThread.ToInt32();

    var threadState = (ThreadState)threadInformation.ThreadState;
    var threadWaitReason = GetThreadWaitReason((int)threadInformation.WaitReason);

    Console.WriteLine($"-- [{threadId}] {threadState}:{threadWaitReason}");

    currentPtr = checked((IntPtr)((long)currentPtr + Marshal.SizeOf(threadInformation)));
}
```

Тут я думаю вы и сами догадались как все работает. Мы сдвигаем поинтер на размер `processInformation`, и с этого места берем информацию о каждом потоке процесса, о кол-ве, котором говорит значение `NumberOfThreads`. Занеся все в нужную структуру мы без труда может вытянуть все нам необходимое, включая и тот самый статус, ради которого все это затевалось.

Результатом будет такое:

> [1444] svchost.exe
> -- [1440] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [3576] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [5380] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [5388] Wait:EventPairLow
> -- [5856] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [5780] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [5864] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [37288] Wait:EventPairLow
>
> [1500] WindscribeService.exe
> -- [1512] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [4540] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [4560] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [4596] Wait:ExecutionDelay
> -- [14324] Wait:EventPairLow
>
> [1984] svchost.exe
> -- [1980] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [4304] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [7960] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [6792] Wait:EventPairLow
> -- [18268] Wait:UserRequest
> -- [2944] Wait:EventPairLow

Вот по сути и все, что вам нужно, дальше уже я думаю вы сами справитесь, сделаете массив/коллекцию/словарь, в которую поместите нужную вам лично информацию, потоки, и т.д. Ну а заморожен процесс или нет, тут уже смотрите на статусы потоков и их причину, если они все имеют `threadWaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.Suspended`, то процесс можно считать замороженным, правда тут могу ошибаться, я не особый спец в процессах, это лишь мои наблюдения, которые основаны на подобном (серый - заморожен):

[image: ProcessInfo]